# Yii2 dropdown different Activerecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2, yii2-model

I'm creating a form to input product which has activeDropdownList to select product category from different table.
I'm using ActiveRecord class in product and category models and use category models to populate dropdown list.
When i'm trying to insert product, it's failed because the dropdownlist's name.

All other field's name is like `name="CreateEvent[tanggal]">`, and my category dropdown : `name="id">`

How to integrate it without hardcoding dropdown attribute?

On my controller :

```
$kategori = $items = ArrayHelper::map(Kategori::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama');

        // check post header, call $model->save() if post is exist
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('status', 'success');
            return $this->redirect(['create']);
        }
```

On my view :

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
echo $form->field($model, 'nama')->input('text');
echo $form->field($model, 'lokasi')->input('text');
echo $form->field($model, 'tanggal')->widget(DatePicker:: classname(),
    [
    ]);
echo Html::activeDropDownList($model,'id',$kategori,[]);
echo Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, 
What is your column name in product table where you saving the categories?

instead of using HTML why not you are using something like this:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$form->field($model,'your column name')->dropdownlist(ArrayHelper::map(Kategori::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama'));
```

Comment: it works, thank you.
i'm sorry for asking such a basic question, i'm new to yii

Answer (score 0):

The field in your table would be something like 'category_id'.

Your dropdown code should therefore be

```
echo Html::activeDropDownList($model,'category_id',$kategori,[]);
```

Comment: it works too
i think i have tried it before but it didn't work, i don't know why
thanks